# How to set up VS-Code to open new files in current instance?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I've been using Visual Studio Code recently and I really like it. However, every time I open a file, a new window will open rather than a new "tab." I've already tried setting `window.openInNewWindow` to `false` and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated answer since 1.11**:

```
"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off"
```

Accepted values are now `"on" "off" "default"`

Comment: This is what worked for me on a new install. False does not work anymore.

Comment: And in-case you're not able to edit your settings.json file:    

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977789/cannot-change-visual-studio-code-settings

Answer (score 31):

**Edit regarding VSCode 1.9.0**

The VSCode team has changed the default settings since 1.9.0, it should now be the default behavior.
If VS Code is still not reusing the same window, you can enforce this behavior with:

`"window.openFilesInNewWindow": off`

They have also extended the settings available to configure those behaviors ([see release note here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_9#_control-whether-to-open-a-new-window-or-use-last-active)).

**Original answer**

This is currently supported by the latest version of VSCode and solution is detailed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180829/open-multiple-files-in-one-vs-code-instance).

Simply add the following setting to your user setting:

`"window.openFilesInNewWindow": false`

Tested and approved with VSCode 1.4.0 :)

Comment: This is the proper answer. Tested and approved with VSCode 1.8.1.

Comment: My answer below is now the most up to date: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43498553/1748123

Comment: What you are referencing is what I already added to my answer. It was added in VSCode 1.9, not 1.11. Default settings (`default`) should do the job for most cases.

Comment: Please unmark this as the answer. My answer below should be

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit multiple files in the same directory then open the root directory.

If you want to edit multiple files that aren't in the same directory use the command line to open code with multiple files. See [documentation here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics#_additional-command-line-arguments). Copied below for reference.

```
code file1 file2 file3
```

See [setup](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/setup) to get Code on the command line.

Comment: The tab functionality is not really the point of the original question. For posterity: VS-Code 1.3 supports tabs but still opens files in a new window, rather than the current one.

Comment: Add the `-r` flag and it won't open in a new window - `code -r file1 file2 file3`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `"workbench.editor.enablePreview"=false`