# When opening files with external app, how to open them in the same IDE instance?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code Insiders (daily builds) since it is the only version that supports Tab view for opened files.

I am opening my files using FileZilla directly from the FTP and everytime I open a new file. VS Code opens up a new app window with the new file.

Is there a way for me to tell the editor to open every new file in a separate tab in the current window?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem. It is simple, You have to add the following setting in your User Settings file:

```
"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "on"
```

> So for this to work, you have to set its boolean value to **false.**
> e.g **"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off"**
>
> Go to ***Preferences - User Settings*** , and this will automatically open the ***settings.json*** file for You.
>
> [image]

Comment: In my case (version 1.32.1) File > Preferences > Settings: then find openFilesInNewWindow and turn it on.

Answer (score 2):

**VSCode** - version **1.32.3**

**Disable Editor Preview** mode by:

File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Editor Management ->

1. **Enable Preview** (**uncheck**)
2. **Enable Preview From Quick Open** (**uncheck**)

From Visual Studio Code documentation:

> When you single-click or select a file in the Explorer, it is shown in
>   a preview mode and reuses an existing Tab.
>
> If you'd prefer to not use
>   preview mode and always create a new Tab, you can control the behavior
>   with these settings:
>
> workbench.editor.enablePreview to globally enable or disable preview
>   editors workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen to enable or
>   disable preview editors when opened from Quick Open

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_preview-mode