# Visual Studio Code - Open file in new tab, not in new window

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

I need help to configure VSCode. I actually use VSCode to edit files directly from filezilla (right click on my file / Edit).
But if i edit a second file, VSCode open a new window. However, i would like to see all my files in the same window, in different tabs.

How can i do this please ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180829/when-opening-files-with-external-app-how-to-open-them-in-the-same-ide-instance